# How to navigate Google App Maker tabs which are out of panel range

Tags: tabs, google-app-maker

New to Google App Maker. I created a Tab Widget with multiple tabs which had exceeded my panels width. It seems that I can't navigate to that tab which is out of sight. Am I missing any layout settings?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about increasing the width of the 'Tab' component? This will add a horizontal scroll bar in your page but you will be able to visualize the component. You can do so from 'Layout' tab shown in below screen.

[image: Layout Setting]

If this does not work for you then try redesigning your page and add multiple 'Tab' elements.